# How do i disable automatic indentation in Python/IDLE on every new line?

Tags: python, indentation, python-idle

Whenever i break to a new line in IDLE, my cursor starts at an indentation regardless of whether a colon precedes it or not. How do i disable this?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Apparently i hadn't indented a break command, so every new line after it was automatically indented.

Comment: You can delete your own questions and answers.  There should be a 'delete' button next to 'edit'